# Best way to set bits of fields in union

Tags: c++, c++11, bit-fields

Let's say I have the following

```
struct S {
union {
    uint8_t flags;
    struct {
        uint8_t flag2bits : 2;
        uint8_t flag1bit : 1;
    };
};
};

S s;
s.flag2bits = 2;
s.flag1bit = 1; // this will wipe out the values of other bits
```

What's the best way to assign value to a specific bit without affecting other bit fields?

I can shift around and then assign and then shift again but it means once someone changes the order of the bit fields, the code is broken....

Comment: Writing to one bitfield does not mess with the others, that would make bitfields absolutely useless - http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3bbf315576887706

Comment: @Praetorian Unless there is more than one thread.

Comment: @AlanStokes every statement about C++ behaviour implicitly has "unless there is undefined behaviour"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can shift around and then assign and then shift again but it means
>   once someone changes the order of the bit fields, the code is
>   broken....

No, it doesn't mean the code is broken. You can change the bitfields whatever (in any order/you can leave some of them unset) you like

In your example:

```
S s;
s.flag2bits = 2;
s.flag1bit = 1;
```

Changing `flag2bits` will not affect value stored in `flag1bit`.

However, your problem may be related to the `union` you hold in your `struct`. Changing the **`flags`** variable *will* affect both of the bitfields, as you are storing them in a separate `struct`.

I hope this example will explain the case here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
struct S {
    union {
        uint8_t flags;
        struct {
            uint8_t flag2bits : 2;
            uint8_t flag1bit : 1;
        };
    };
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    S s;
    s.flag2bits = 2;
    s.flag1bit = 1;

    std::cout << int(s.flag2bits) << int(s.flag1bit) << std::endl;
    s.flags = 4;  // As you are using union, at this point you are overwriting
                  // values stored in your (nested) struct
    std::cout << int(s.flag2bits) << int(s.flag1bit) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** As @M.M points out,  [it's undefined behavior to read from the member of the union that wasn't most recently written](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union). Though at least on clang-3.5, the code above would print:

```
21
01
```

which illustrates the point I am trying to make (i.e. overwriting of union fields).

I would consider removing `union` from your `struct S` code, though I may not see the whole picture of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Reading `s.flag2bits` after writing `s.flags` causes undefined behaviour: in C++ only the most recently-written member of a union may be read

Comment: @M.M Thanks, I've added that to my answer.

Comment: @M.M new to me. So does it mean if I write to s.flag2bits and then s.flag1bit, then the behavior of reading from s.flag2bits is undefined?  Or then the behavior of reading from s.flags is undefined?  Just trying to understand.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The C++ compiler will manage the bits for you. You can just set the values as you have it. Only the appropriate bits will be set.

Did you try it?